# Is it true that if any two of $m$, $n$, and $mn$ are sums of two integer squares, then so is the third?

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

Where m and n are positive integers. Prove or give a counter example.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, on this site we use MathJaX to format our maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a basic tutorial.

Comment: Do youy consider $0$ to be integer square?

Comment: In class 0 was considered to be an integer

Answer (score 2):

The following identity, often called the *Brahmagupta Identity*, will help you:
$$(a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)=(ax\pm by)^2 +(ay\mp bx)^2.$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta-Fibonacci_identity

Comment: It's not clear from the above identity  that if $mn$ and $n$ are sums of two squares of integers, so will be $m$. I can only get that $m$ will be a sum of two squares of rational numbers.

Comment: @orangeskid Of course, but we know much more about the sum of two squares (e.g., [Fermat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares)).

Comment: I'm not sure where to go with this. I have assumed that mn and m are sum of two squares but I can't find how to prove n is also a sum of two squares

Comment: By assumption, the primes $p\equiv 3 \bmod 4$ appearing in $nm$ and $m$ have even multiplicity. Hence the same is true for $n$, which means that $n$ is the sum of two squares.

Answer (score 1):

A non-trivial characterization is:

> An integer is a sum of two squares iff its prime factors of the form $4k+3$ appear with even exponent in the factorization.

This will make it easy to answer your original  question.